# How to copy files from root directory of a failed ubuntu drive

Tags: permissions, copy

My Ubuntu Desktop 22.04 system is stuck booting into emergency mode. So I thought I would backup my files and data and reinstall everything from scratch.

I plugged my SSD and Hard drive to my Windows PC and copying stuff over there. Issue starts when I try to copy anything that's not under `/home/user` directory. I am trying to copy certain files from `/var/lib` but I am getting permission denied everytime.

How do I solve this issue as I can't think of a way to boot into ubuntu and access root user.

Comment: AFAIK Windows doesn't support Linux/Unix filesystems ... I would recommend booting into a live system and do the copying from there ... I, also wouldn't bother copying files under `/var/lib` or any other system directory for that matter as those can either come with a fresh install or can be installed with other packages ... The only exception might be customized configuration files

Comment: How would I go about copying files from root directory with a live USB of ubuntu? Also I am mostly copying my MySQL databases from `/var/lib` which aren't stored anywhere else afaik.